# How Can I Make Xbox Live Indie Games At No Cost?

Tags: xna, xbox360, xbox

Is there a way I can make free Xbox Live Indie Games? Now I don't mean to publish it to the world on the marketplace but I just mean to test it on my Xbox for free. I know you have to download the XNA app on your Xbox and PC but do I need the XNA Creators Club subscription to test the games on my Xbox? If I do, is there an alternative way to make and test Xbox games? I know you can make a student account on the Microsoft website and get the subscription for free but I am still in high school and it doesn't really look like high school students can do qualify for it. Even if they can, I couldn't find my school in there choices of schools so it doesn't make a difference. Is there a way to make and test Xbox Live Indie Games free? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can not deploy to the Xbox without the subscription.

You are limited to building and testing on the PC.  There is no restriction for building on your computer, so start coding and try it out if you end up with a finished or near finished game then you can decide if it is worth dropping the 99 dollar fee.

Comment: So I can test it on my computer? I just want to know if I can at least test my game on something.

Comment: Yep. If you want to use a gamepad you'll need a wired xbox controller or the wireless adapter.  Or you can code in mouse + keyboard controls.  When creating a project make it a windows game project instead of an xbox.  Later on you can always right click the project and make a copy for xbox if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To test on an XBox you need the XNA Creator's Club subscription, no alternate way at least not officially. (Jailbreaking might work, but that has it's own plethora of technical and possibly legal issues)

Answer (score 0):

In some previous [Dream Build Play Competitions](https://www.dreambuildplay.com/Main/Default.aspx), entering the contest would earn one developer account a free temporary subscription with the ability to deploy to the xBox.  This was not a full developer subscription; the account could not submit games for sale.  But it could test code on the hardware.

Unfortunately, this is not a reliable way to acquire a subscription, and it is never guaranteed that it will even be a part of any given year's contestant perks.

Answer (score 0):

High School students should be able to access [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/) and get a subscription that allows you to test games.

Alternatively you can download [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express) and [XNA Game Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714) then start a Windows Game project, [change the profile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/07/19/selecting-reach-vs-hidef.aspx) to Reach if your graphics card cannot support HiDef and connect a wired Xbox 360 GamePad. The framework is almost exactly the same for Xbox, Windows Phone or Windows platform.