# Testing XNA 4.0 games On the XBOX 360 without paying $100

Tags: xna-4.0, xbox360

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Can I Make Xbox Live Indie Games At No Cost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315320/how-can-i-make-xbox-live-indie-games-at-no-cost)

I have created an Xbox 360 game with XNA 4.0, and i want to test it on the XBOX 360. I do not want to pay the $100 and you no longer get the first year free when signing up for the XNA creators club.. Is there a way to test my games on the XBOX 360 for free?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't a student then you are out of luck! If you are a student, head over to http://dreamspark.com and get an account registered. Dreamspark allows for students to receive microsoft development tools for free!